# Official way to play YouTube video other than YoutubePlayer API

Tags: android, youtube, exoplayer

Is there any official way of to play YouTube videos other than YouTubePlayer API. And is there any violation of policy of YouTube, if I play YouTube videos using ExoPlayer? By using YouTubePlayer API there is a limit to customize player. I want to make my own button in the player and ExoPlayer allow me to do this. Just like Ampme is not using YouTubePlayer API for playing YouTube videos. [Here](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/5466#issuecomment-460049029) it says that ExoPlayer is not used for playing YouTube videos officially.

UPDATED:
By exploring I found the [library](https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player#youtubeplayerlistener) which is officially playing YouTube videos by using the YouTubePlayer API but the limitation is I cannot change the speed of the playback. I need to change the playback speed.